# How would you create n nested loops for math?

Tags: c#, loops, nested, nested-loops

So, I am trying to wrap my head around understanding how you can use a variable to denote *how many times a loop is nested*.

Here is an example I write up to simulate the output of `dimensions = 4`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int dimensions = 4;    // e.g. for (1, 2, 3, 4), dimensions = 4

        Console.WriteLine($"{addNumbers(dimensions)}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static long addNumbers(int dimensions)
    {
        long number = 0;

        // hard coded to be dimensions = 4
        for (int h = 0; h <= dimensions; h++)
            for (int i = 0; i <= dimensions; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j <= dimensions; j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k <= dimensions; k++)
                        number += h + i + j + k;    // just some random math

        return number;
    }
```

This will present the expected output of:

```
5000
```

So to readdress the problem, how can I code to allow this for **n dimensions**? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let Recursion be your friend

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about recursion, but I cannot figure out how I would do it.

Comment: How important is the "number += h + i + j + k" line, because that's really the only thing that makes it slightly tricky (you'd need an array to hold all the counters instead)?

Comment: This is just filler code for now, I want to do more complex math at a later date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary `n` dimensions you can loop with a help of *array* `int[] address` which represents `n` dimensions:

```
  static long addNumbers(int dimensions) {
    int[] address = new int[dimensions];

    // size of each dimension; not necessary equals to dimensions
    // + 1 : in your code, int the loops you have i <= dimensions, j <= dimensions etc.
    int size = dimensions + 1;

    long number = 0;

    do {
      //TODO: some math here
      //      i == address[0]; j = address[1]; ... etc.
      number += address.Sum(); 

      // next address: adding 1 to array
      for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; ++i) {
        if (address[i] >= size - 1)
          address[i] = 0;
        else {
          address[i] += 1;
          break; 
        }
      }
    }  
    while (!address.All(index => index == 0)); // all 0 address - items're exhausted

    return number; 
  }
```

Finally, let's add some *Linq* to look at the results:

```
  int upTo = 5;

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(1, upTo)
    .Select(i => $"{i} -> {addNumbers(i),6}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1 ->      1 
2 ->     18
3 ->    288
4 ->   5000 // <- We've got it: 5000 for 4 dimensions
5 ->  97200
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be it!

Comment: Using *array* for addressing is a typical way out in case of arbitrary n dimension space, array, collection etc.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431650/how-to-create-a-n-dimensional-array-of-all-combination-of-number/53431999#53431999

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed the post! I didn't need the loop to print the console, my mistake!

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin: Thank you! I see; I've added *Linq* for debugging purpose: since `n = 1` case solution (`32`) was very *suspicious*